# Retrive the id as per single element from an array of a coloumn

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an table like this. I want to retrieve the product_id by selecting the "level_id" which are "20" from "misc" column. Any idea guys how to do that in mySQL ?

```
product_id    misc
----------    ------
1            {"level_id":20,"group_id":"2132","product_name":"bg","category_id":6}
2            {"level_id":20,"group_id":"2132","product_name":"bg","category_id":6} 
3            {"level_id":25,"group_id":"2132","product_name":"bg","category_id":6} 
4            {"level_id":28,"group_id":"2132","product_name":"bg","category_id":6}
5            {"level_id":28,"group_id":"2132","product_name":"bg","category_id":6} 
6            {"level_id":20,"group_id":"2132","product_name":"bg","category_id":6}
```

Please help me ...
Actually its an json array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression in your mysql query to get record with level_id = 20. It is **untested**. Pls check.

```
select * from table_name where misc REGEXP '(.*\"level_id\":\"20\".*)'
```

Comment: If you find 100% working solution, then edit my answer. It'll be helpful for others too :-)

Comment: Yes its working. But it depends on the string. Your answer will work for group_id not for level_id. For level_id you need to write like '(.*\"level_id\":\20\.*)'

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you stored JSON inside MySQL. MySQL has no native JSON suport at the moment (for production that is) (See here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50382/do-sql-server-or-mysql-contain-json-supporting-functions). 
Either you are tasked with writing your own JSON parser, or you should do this outside MySQL (PHP, Java etc) or you have to save the data different.